# how to write a script that will launch java application using the bundled jre?

Tags: bash, java, batch-file

basically I have MyApplication.jar and a nasty native library that will only work with 32-bit JRE. I bundled the 32-bit JRE in the /JREF folder resides in the same directory as the MyApplication.jar

How to write a script that will launch MyApplication.jar using the bundled JRE inside the /JREF directory.

Possible for a script to run on windows, mac, and linux?

Comment: Write a small Java program that unzips the Jar and runs java.exe with the correct parameters to launch the real program under a different class name?

Comment: Hi unfortunately no. If the user already has 64-bit JRE it will end up using that instead as I've read. The unziping of jar to a temproary location is a possibility but my requirement is that the java application run the bundled 32-bit JRE I included.

Comment: What I mean is you allow the host's JVM (whatever version) to run the small piece of program that extracts the 32-bit JVM and uses Runtime.exec() to run the JVM as a separated process with parameters pointing to the real entry point (class name) of your main program.

Comment: +1'd. Ah now I see. Actually that is a really great solution. I will keep that in mind but for the time being I am looking to use scripts to launch the application.